# There is a way to evaluate the limit superior of a sequence?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there a way to evaluate the limit superior of a sequence? 
I didn't find any information about this in the documentation center.

The limit superior of a sequence $(x_n)$ is defined as

$$\limsup x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\{x_k:k\ge n\}=\inf\{\sup\{x_k:k\ge n\}:n\in\Bbb N\}$$

Comment: Theoretically, `Assuming[n ∈ Integers, Limit[MaxValue[{x[k], k >= n}, k, Integers], n -> Infinity]]`, but practically there are probably limitations depending on `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Max[Limit[expr, n -> Infinity]] 
(*expr is a function of n*)
```

I think you can try this because the limit superior of a sequence usually gives an interval. 
I don't have the privilege to comment here, therefore, I leave my suggestion for you.

Comment: The limit superior of a sequence is an unique value. I dont know why you says it is an "interval". More over: your solution dont work if the limit of the sequence doesnt exist. The limit superior of a sequence ever exists, but not the limit. Anyway I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think I should say that because the limit of a sequence from Mathematica (If it works.) probably gives an interval.(I guess) 
Then you just take the max value of the interval.
ex. `Limit[(-1)^n (1 + 1/n), n -> Infinity]` gives `(*E^(2 I Interval[{0, \[Pi]}])*)`

Comment: Oh, I understand... thank you very much. I will try to know this behavior of mathematica.