# Computing a limit symbollically, it is possible?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to compute this limit symbollically

```
Limit[Abs[1 - a^k]^(1/k), k -> Infinity]
```

but it does nothing. I tried defining `a` inside a domain as `Integers` but it doesnt work.

But if I write, by example, this

```
Limit[Abs[1 - 5^k]^(1/k), k -> Infinity]
```

it is evaluated to `5` almost instantly. There is a way to express some limits symbolically? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Limit[(a^k - 1)^(1/k), k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a > 1]
```

Comment: can you put an eye to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130010/there-is-a-way-to-evaluate-the-limit-superior-of-a-sequence) please?